# Comparing date using callback form validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I made a callback and have an if condition that compares the input field payment date to the last payment date from the database and the date today. It shouldnt be equal or earlier than the last payment date and should be equal or less than the date today.

It returns false when i choose a date that is greater than the date today but it returns true even if the date i chose is equal or earlier than the last payment date.

I tried comparing the input field and the last payment date inside the controller and not in the callback function and it works just fine. When i echo the $projectID inside comparePaymentDate it display the date from input date field instead of the project id. But when i echoed the $projectID inside the validatePaymentAdd function it shows correct the project id.

In my controller

```
$validate = $this->my_form_validation_lib->validatePaymentAdd($projectID);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($validate);
```

and the callback

```
public function comparePaymentDate($projectID){
    $latestPayment = $this->payment_model->getLatestPayment($projectID);
    $fieldPaymentDate = strtotime($this->input->post('form_payment_date'));

    if($fieldPaymentDate <= strtotime($latestPayment['payment_date']) || $fieldPaymentDate > strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('comparePaymentDate', 'Payment Date should be later date than the latest payment and earlier or equal to the date today.');
        return FALSE;
    } else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Function from my custom library that returns the rules

```
function validatePaymentAdd($projectID){
            $rules = array(
                array(
                    'field' =>  'form_milestone',
                    'label' =>  'Milestone',
                    'rules' =>  'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces'
                ),
                array(
                    'field' =>  'form_payment_date',
                    'label' =>  'Payment Date',
                    'rules' =>  'required|callback_comparePaymentDate['.$projectID.']'
                ),
                array(
                    'field' =>  'form_payment_made',
                    'label' =>  'Amount Paid',
                    'rules' =>  array(
                        'trim', 'required', 'greater_than_equal_to[0]',
                        'callback_payment'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'field' =>  'form_payment_remarks',
                    'label' =>  'Payment Remarks',
                    'rules' =>  'trim|required'
                ),
                array(
                    'field' =>  'remarks_subject',
                    'label' =>  'Remarks Subject',
                    'rules' =>  'trim|required'
                ),
                array(
                    'field' =>  'remarks_field',
                    'label' =>  'Remarks',
                    'rules' =>  'trim|required'
                )
            );
            return $rules;
        }
```

Function that gets the last payment date from the database

```
public function getLatestPayment($projectID){
        $this->db->select('payment_date');
    $this->db->from('payment');
    $this->db->where('project_id', $projectID);
    $this->db->order_by('payment_id', 'Desc');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $payment = $this->db->get();
        return $payment->row_array();
}
```

Ex:
Input date: 5/2/2019
Last payment date: 5/5/2019

It should return false and return an error

Comment: what is your date format?

Comment: @RahulMeshram Its also Y-m-d the same format i used when i compare it to the date today

Comment: Check this `if ($fieldPaymentDate > strtotime($latestPayment['payment_date']) && $fieldPaymentDate <= time()) {
    return true;
} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('comparePaymentDate', 'Payment Date should be later date than the latest payment and earlier or equal to the date today.');
    return false;
}` replace your condition with mine and check

Comment: @RahulMeshram Still the same result

Comment: can you post $fieldPaymentDate, strtotime($latestPayment['payment_date']) and values in comparePaymentDate function

Comment: @RahulMeshram Oh what when i echo the value of $projectID at the validatePaymentAdd function it returns the project id but when i call it at callback it shows the same value as the date from input field. The $latestPayment['payment_date'] returns nothing

Comment: @RahulMeshram Solved the problem thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.
Apparently the first parameter in callback function is the input field and the second parameter is the data that you want to pass.

So the callback now is

```
public function uniqueProjectName($input_field, $clientID){
    $projectName = $this->client_profile_model->compareProjectName($clientID);
    if($projectName > 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('uniqueProjectName', 'Project Name should be unique.');
        return FALSE;
    } else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```